# How to select an item in a gtk.IconView (Python)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, selection

In a gtk.IconView I can use get_selected_items() to find the paths of the items a user selected in the view.

I'm now looking for the corresponding method to set the selection of an IconView. But I can't find any!? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [select_path()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkiconview.html#method-gtkiconview--select-path) method. I somehow missed it on scanning through the docs.